# Does one need to worry about feeding his pet gebrokhts or kitniyot on Pesach?

Tags: passover, animals, kitniyos-semigrain-legume, gebrochts

I thought I had seen just about every unusual Pesach food item, but, it seems that each year, some other idea comes out. I just saw this in my neighborhood store.

[image: Pesach Pet Food]

Ashkenazim don't eat *kitniyot* and many don't eat *gebrokhts*. Does one need to worry about these things when feeding a pet? Is this a marketing gimmick, or is there something behind making and selling this product that makes this pet restriction necessary?

I'm not sure if this dog is wearing a Borsallino, though :-)

Comment: Well, quite honestly, dogs and cats don't need kosher food, either. But here it is, kosher pet food.

Comment: @ezra no, but they do need chametz-free food on Pesach

Comment: There's the famous joke about the fish who died on Pesach (despite being fed Matzah) because it was Makpid on Gebrokts...

Comment: @Daniel Indeed, but not kitniyot and gebrocht-free. :) And the food doesn't have to have a hechsher. Look online, there are lists from the OU, OK, Star-K, etc. with Kosher L'Pesach pet foods.

Comment: kitniyot is not a problem http://cor.ca/view-515-pet-food-on-passover-and-throughout-the-yearhtml.html as for gebrochts, I would think that the pet should abide by his father's minhag.

Comment: @rosends This is quickly turning into a PTIJ

Comment: @rosends The "P" that ezra refers to stands for Pesach, not Purim. *Mo'adim Lesimcha*.